# React : Set Radio button value's based on condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router

In react how do we set the value based on the condition. The radio buttons are only for visual representation. These values wont be saved in the data base or read form the database.

For example I need to make the radio(sales-team-yes) checked based on the other value customerService.onField not null.

```html
<div className="col-xs-2">
                <div className="field-label">Sales Team?</div>
                <Field
                    id="sales-team-yes"
                    label="Yes"
                    /* name="salesTeam" */
                    component={RadioField}
                    type="radio"
                    checked={customerService.onField != null ? true : false}
                   /* value={customerService.onField != null ? true : false}*/
                    readOnly
                    disabled/>
                <Field
                    id="sales-team-no"
                    label="No"
                   /* name="salesTeam" */
                    component={RadioField}
                    type="radio"
                    checked={customerService.onField == null ? false : true}
                   /* value={customerService.onField != null ? true : false}*/
                    readOnly
                    disabled/>
                </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: which library do you import ```Feild``` from? What you have to use is RadioGroup I guess instead of individual radios

Comment: I've downvoted this because you haven't shown the implementation of Field or RadioField in particular so no one can help unless they know where those come from

Comment: @DominicTobias  I am newbie to the React I added the implementation for Radio now

Comment: @NoushadPP I added the code please check it out

Comment: You've put two components there - Input and Radio, which of these is Field and RadioField?

Comment: @ssl please create a [codepen](http://codepen.io) that we can look into. this information is not enough to find your issue.